# Delphi: PAServer: Acquiring permission to support debugging...failed

Tags: xcode, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Delphi 10.2.3  MacOS Mojave (which I'm regretting)

I had Xcode 10 and it didn't work with Delphi. I removed Xcode 10 and I installed Xcode 9.4.1 and its command tools.

The PAServer continues to give this message on startup:

Acquiring permission to support debugging...failed

Delphi hangs during the "Launching:" phase of deploying an iOS app.

Everything worked fine before I upgraded to Mohave and tried Xcode 10.

What's a guy got to do to get Delphi 10.2.3 to debug iOS apps with Xcode 9 on Mojave?

Comment: I think this means the password for the PAServer is invalid.. Maybe try launching it from the commandline using these instructions  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Running_the_Platform_Assistant_on_a_Mac

Comment: When I follow the Terminal directions, the ls command lists only the Utilities folder. I'm starting to think that my upgrade to Mojave left my MacOS login with fewer privileges.

Comment: I also tried:
/usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable
in Terminal. It responded with:
Developer mode is already enabled.

Comment: Have you tried removing your current PAServer install and reinstalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what fixed it. I deployed a blank iOS app from Xcode. Then Delphi started deploying normally again, including stepping into the debugger.

I have no idea what magic Xcode did to clear the logjam.

Comment: I've been contemplating updating to Mojave on my "real machine". It all works OK on a beta of Mojave I have on a VM. If you have it all working OK, I'm more inclined to update now :-)

Comment: I also have MacOS Mojave and XCode 9.4.1.  XCode is signing its apps ok, but PAServer 19 fails to ask debugging permission (the password dialog doesn't show). Just fails to get permission.

Comment: @OmarReis I am also seeing this.

Answer (score 5):

The following seems to work: 
Start the PAServer in Terminal under root:

```
sudo ./paserver
```

or set permissions for dbkosx as follows:

```
sudo chown root dbkosx_25_0 
sudo chmod u+s,g+x dbkosx_25_0
```

Assuming you are in the PAServer-19.0.app/Contents/MacOS/ folder. If not, then execute this first:

```
cd /Applications/PAServer-19.0.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

Comment: It seems to be the Delphi OS X debugger